# Displaying element in my text file when it is lesser than the range?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a Top 5 leaderboard for my game in Python 3.

**Here's what I have**

```
Top_Score = open("highscore.txt", "r+")
score_list = []
    
print("   Top 5")
print("==========")
for line in Top_Score.readlines():  # Read lines
    score_list.append(line)
score_list.sort()
for i in range(5):
    print("Pos", str(i + 1), ":", score_list[i])
print("==========")
Top_Score.close()
```

**highscore.txt**

> ```
> 50
> 18
> 20
> 40
> 50
> 60
> 70
> ```

**Output**

```
   Top 5
==========
Pos 1 : 18

Pos 2 : 20

Pos 3 : 40

Pos 4 : 50

Pos 5 : 50

==========
```

But how can I display element in my text file if it is lesser than the range(5) without any errors? Any help would be appreciated

**Example highscore.txt**

> ```
> 50
> 18
> 20
> ```

**Example Output**

```
   Top 5
==========
Pos 1 : 18

Pos 2 : 20

Pos 3 : 50

==========
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the print loop, you need to check if the size of the list is smaller than 5. If so, only loop until the size.

So, something like this:

```
loop_range = 5
if len(score_list) < loop_range:
    loop_range = len(score_list)
for i in range(loop_range):
   print("Pos", str(i + 1), ":", score_list[i])
```

This can be rewritten using the `min` function to select the smaller of the two numbers, 5 or the size:

```
loop_range = min(5, len(score_list))
for i in range(loop_range):
   print("Pos", str(i + 1), ":", score_list[i])
```